# Resolution after zooming UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, resolution

After zooming a `UIWebView` which is loaded with an HTML string, the content is blurred. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why you want to zoom a UIWebView, is it a requirement. I will always prefer to increase/decrease the font size of the text rather than zoom the webView.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `@property(nonatomic) BOOL scalesPageToFit` property of your UIWebView instance is set to YES (default value is NO).

What content specifically is blurred?  Graphic content will become blurred once it has been zoomed in too much.

Comment: I'm loading an HTML string into the UIWebView. The HTML string has text and images. Both the text and the image get blurred. The scalesPageToFit is set to YES.

Comment: You can actually see a similar behavior if you zoom an email message on the Mail App. The content gets blurred (including the text), but as soon as you stop zooming, it isn't blurred anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to solve it.

However, you can easily solve it when iOS 5.0 is out.

UIWebView has a UIScrollView subview in 5.0, so you can set the Maximum Scale Factor.

Comment: But if I zoom a UITableView, the same happens: I can zoom, but it is blurred. Don't I have to do something special in scrollViewDidEndZooming?

Comment: Zooming a UITableView? I've never tried this before,sorry :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have a odd-solution.

To Zoom scrollView:

```
if (!self.webView.scrollView.isZooming) {
    [self.webView.scrollView setZoomScale:scale];
}
```

The zooming is done:

```
CGFloat differenceForReload = 0.001f;
[self.webView.scrollView setZoomScale:scale - differenceForReload];
[self.webView.scrollView setZoomScale:scale + differenceForReload
                             animated:YES];
```